# What is the purpose of the 2 semicolons inside "for(;;){ }"?

Tags: loops, date, for-loop, time

Why are there 2 semicolons in this for loop? This code works correctly but I would like to know how this works. Any help is appreciated :)

```
public void CurrentDate() {

    Thread clock = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            for (;;) {
                try {

                    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    date.setText("Date:  " + year + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + day);

                    int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                    time.setText("Time: " + hour + ":" + (minute) + ":" + second);

                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) 
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    clock.start();
}
```

Comment: ist a ***for*** ever loop

Comment: It is used to execute for loop without terminating it or without checking any condition.But the thread will be stopped for one second as you have written in the code and after one second ,loop will start its execution and will stop for one second and this thing goes on and you will simply get a clock.

Answer (score 0):

when writing a for loop, in many languages omitting the conditions normally found you are telling the system that it is *unconditional* -- meaning the for loop will run forever unless something breaks out of the loop.

this is often used to set up a function that will run endlessly as a daemon in a system, or something that will run for the duration of the client-side experience.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A for loop usually looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Or, [more generally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Traditional_for-loops):

```
for (/* initialization */; /* condition */; /* afterthought */)
```

In your for loop, each of these parts is empty:

```
for (;;)
```

This means the for loop does no initialization, checks no condition, and has no afterthought. So it simply means "loop forever."